# Error plotting with cairo on igraph: module 'cairo' has no attribute 'Surface'

Tags: python-3.x, igraph, cairo, pycairo

I'm trying to plot a graph in `iGraph` but keep getting an error associated with `cairo`.

```
import igraph as ig
import cairocffi as cairo

# [generate graph]
ig.plot(graph)
```

gives the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-e4df540328af> in <module>()
----> 1 ig.plot(comms,mark_groups=True)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py in plot(obj, target, bbox, *args, **kwds)
    444         bbox = BoundingBox(bbox)
    445 
--> 446     result = Plot(target, bbox, background=kwds.get("background", "white"))
    447 
    448     if "margin" in kwds:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py in __init__(self, target, bbox, palette, background)
    115         """
    116         self._filename = None
--> 117         self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
    118         self._need_tmpfile = False
    119 

AttributeError: module 'cairo' has no attribute 'Surface'
```

**I've tried:**

Updating pycairo and installing py2cairo (unsuccessfuly).

Updating cairocffi.

Please help!